# Scroll an element in units other than px in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I have a `<div>` like so:

```
#myDiv {
  height: 5em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I want to create a function that scrolls this `<div>` down by `1em`, and exactly `1em`. I'm currently doing this:

```
const myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
const myDivHeight = myDiv.offsetHeight;
myDiv.scrollTo(0, myDivHeight / 5); // 1em?? but not really...
```

However, this has slight problems as a result of the actual height being in sub-pixels, causing a division by 5 to just cause some real problems.

Is there a more elegant solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use css calc function.

Comment: `scrollIntoView` maybe could be a workaround?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Not a bad idea! But perhaps a slightly more elegant solution exists... (hopefully...)

Comment: @connexo That's something new. Could you describe how I can control (or perhaps simulate control) of a `<div>`'s scrolling using CSS?

Comment: Well I assume your problem is knowing exactly how many pixels are equivalent to 5em. Right?

Comment: `calc` is still going to give you an approximate (and not integer) value in pixels and you'd have to apply it to an off-screen element to get it, so in the end probably the same as doing the math yourself.

Comment: Could you create an (invisible) element inside #myDiv, which would be 1em from the top of of it, and scroll to this invisible 'marker' element?

Comment: Yup, that's what I was hinting at too, create invisible elements inside the div and use `scrollIntoView` on them.

Comment: Sounds good! That's the approach I'm going with for the time being, until I find a better solution. Thanks guys!